# Why doesn’t [NSArray class] return what I expected?

Tags: iphone, parsing, nsarray

I am trying to parse some JSON that I get via a web service. The logic is :

```
id jsonObject = ....;      //This can be string or array 

if([jsonObject class] == [NSString class] || [jsonObject class] == [NSMutableString class]{

// DO some thing
}
else if([jsonObject class] = [NSArray class] || [jsonObject class] == [NSMutableArray class]{

// Do some thing else
}
```

However for one of the elements I ran into a weird problem. The class of this element should be NSArray but when I run the code I see the class as __NSArrayM. This does not match the second if block.

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use instead:

```
if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
}
```

For class clusters, this is the only proper way to do it -- isKindOfClass checks whether an object is an instance of a class or one of its subclasses. There's a similar method, isMemberOfClass:, which tests for strict class equality/membership (i. e. no subclass instances are considered equal).

Comment: I wish I could have given you 2 up votes ... I wasted 4 hrs trying to debug this....

Comment: @user1454940 no problem, I'm glad I could help (btw the accept gives me 15 rep so you essentially gave me two and a half ;)